# Window.open with '_blank' consumes parent tab memory

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, window.open, window.opener

```
var yourWindow = window.open();
yourWindow.opener = null;
yourWindow.location = "http://someurl.here";
yourWindow.target = "_blank";
```

the above code opens a new tab in ajax success without popup blocker, as expected, but it consumes the parent tab memory.

[image]

[image]

Is there anything I can do to solve this case? Please help me in fixing this, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What issue does that cause? Other browsers will put even more tabs in a process, too – are you only targeting Chrome?

Comment: Do you think consumer really cares about it?

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Do you think consumer really cares about it? - Yes, they do. 

Refer the screenshot in my edited post.

Both of my browsers crash consistently chrome and firefox when I open multiple tabs in above scenerio.

Answer (score 1):

I've meet this problem too,I resolve it with create a link, set attributes and which most important is '[res noopener](https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/)', and then trigger click event

```js
function openNonpener (url) {
  let link = document.createElement('a')
  link.setAttribute('href', url)
  link.setAttribute('target', '_blank')
  link.setAttribute('rel', 'noopener')
  link.click()
}
```

Comment: This solved my memory leak problem I had using window.open. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I think you may be going about this the wrong way - because you are trying to open a tab/window using javascript but still using html attributes.

Consider using the following instead:

```
function openThis(u, t){
// where:...
// u= someURL,  t=TabId (or "" for new tab/win everytime)
  var tgtw = window.open(u,t);  //open the tab/window
      tgtw.focus();             //ff has issues, works in chrome
}
```

Not sure why you are trying to null out the opener ref since it doesn't apply to a javascript method of opening (it just returns the window object to the calling window - thus increasing memory used by that window/tab).

btw, if you were so inclined, you could declare 'tgtw'  outside the scope of the 'openThis' function, such that it is accessible to other functions, then you can also use a button or some such element to close it using...

```
function closeTab(){
  try{tgtw.close();}catch(err){}
/* the try/catch is probably unnecessary but yer never know,
   given that javascript is becoming less and less dev friendly
   for window/tab calls*/
}
```

hth,

G.